# Google Docs: добавление с помощью Apps Script нового фрагмента в начало новой страницы

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

В процессе выполнения скрипта мне необходимо добавлять в существующий документ новые фрагменты.
Важно, чтобы каждый новый фрагмент был бы размещёт **строго** на новой странице.
Сейчас я решаю проблему с помощью добавленя пустых строк, что крайне неудобно, поскольку зависит от размера шрифта, наличия рисунков и т.д.
Есть ли другой, более надёжный способ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте разрыв страницы [PageBreak](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendPageBreak())